# Number of permutations of letters of the word PENDULAM such that vowels are never togehter

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of permutations of the letters of the word ‘PENDULAM', such that vowels are never together.

(**Approach 1**)I know one solution is to find the permutation that vowels are together (ie; 6!) and subtract it from total number of permutations for the word (ie; 8!).

**Approach 2:** I came across another interesting approach like shown below :

Consonants in the word = $5$ ie;{P,N,D,L,M}

Ways of arranging $5$ letters = $5!$

Consider a case like PNDLM and we insert positions that satisfy the condition of vowels not being together like _P_N_D_L_M_.

So the vowels can be in any of the $6$ dashed positions (which is a equivalent to choosing $3$ out of $6$ positions ie; $6C3$) and vowels for chosen $3$ positions can be arranged among themselves in $3!$ ways. So the number of permutations should be : $6C3 \cdot 3! \cdot 5! = 14400$ (using counting principle)

whereas solution by **Approach 1** would be $= 8! - 6! = 39600$.

Can someone point out where Approach 2 went wrong. I would like to use Approach 2 so that I can solve cases like

> permutation of $2$ vowels not being together

Comment: Did you mean PENDULUM?  PENDULAM is not an English word.  Of course, it is a reasonable question for PENDULAM as well which avoids the complication of having two Us.  My answer is using PENDULAM

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I would interpret the phrase "such that vowels are never together" to mean that no 2 vowels are adjacent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach 1 deducts only cases where all three vowels are together and does not consider the ordering of the vowels.  A correct application of that approach would say there are $8!-6!3!=36000$ ways to order the letters so that all three vowels are not together.

Your approach 2 demands that no pair of vowels be together.  It is a correct solution to a different problem.